# convert a string into uppercase but getting error?

Tags: c++, string

I have a string which I need to convert into UPPERCASE. In my below `getCode` method, I have a string `s` which I need to convert into UPPERCASE.

```
static const Code getCode(std::string const& s)
{
 static std::map<std::string, Code> dataHolderMap{{"TEXT", TEXT},
                                                  {"XML", XML}};

 std::map<std::string, Code>::iterator it = dataHolderMap.find(covertToUpper(s));
 if ( it != dataHolderMap.end() )
 {
    return it->second;
 }
 return XML;
}
```

This is the method I added to convert string into UPPERCASE but I am getting compilation error

```
const char *covertToUpper(char *str) 
{
    char *newstr, *p;
    p = newstr = strdup(str);
    while(*p++=toupper(*p));

    return newstr;
}
```

Error I am getting is:

```
error: no matching function for call
```

Is there anything wrong I am doing? And also what is the best way to do the conversion to UPPERCASE? In general I need to convert incoming string `s` to UPPERCASE.

Comment: On which line are you getting this error message?

Comment: @Cubia Where I am calling `convertToUpper` method. Here `dataHolderMap.find(covertToUpper(s));`

Comment: Why not just pass the string by reference? `void covertToUpper(std::string& str)` or `std::string covertToUpper(const std::string& str)`

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I see, then how does my method will look like? I need to return an UPPERCASE string back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is mixing C++ strings and C-style char * strings. s.c_str() may work, but can't be guaranteed in this case. convertToUpper(s.c_str()) is going to modify the array returned by c_str() and C++ gives no assurances that this will behave the way you want. The next problem will be passing the char * returned by convertToUpper into dataHolderMap.find, which is expecting a string, not a char *.

Best to keep the string a string.

Unless you have a need to preserve the input string s, take a good look at std::transform. If you need to preserve s, make a copy first and run transform on the copy.

```
std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), ::toupper);
```

Will do the conversion you want and keep the string a string so that the call to dataHolderMap.find() gets the string it needs.

```
#include <algorithm> 
...

std::string uppercase = s;    
std::transform(uppercase.begin(), uppercase.end(), uppercase.begin(), ::toupper);
std::map<std::string, Code>::iterator it = dataHolderMap.find(uppercase);
```

Alternative is to use the Boost library in place of transform. Warning: Boost can be a pretty expensive hammer if you don't already have it installed and configured.

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
...

std::map<std::string, Code>::iterator it = dataHolderMap.find(boost::to_upper_copy(s));
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. After adding this, I am getting this exception `error: no matching function for call to transform(std::basic_string<char>::const_iterator, std::basic_string<char>::const_iterator, std::basic_string<char>::const_iterator, <unresolved overloaded function type>)`

Comment: My apologies. should be ::toupper, not std::toupper

Comment: After searching on internet, I tried your suggestion as well but I am getting another error now.

Comment: `/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_algo.h: In instantiation of â_OIter std::transform(_IIter, _IIter, _OIter, _UnaryOperation) [with _IIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char> >; _OIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char> >; _UnaryOperation = int (*)(int)throw ()]:`

Comment: `/home/david/TestProces/wer/common/testserver/http/TestClass.hh:34:78:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_algo.h:4951:2: error: assignment of read-only location â__result.__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::operator*<const char*, std::basic_string<char> >()`

Comment: Didn't notice the const string. You can't modify a constant, so you'll have to make a will have to make a copy. Updating answer.

Answer (score 0):

The only obvious problem that I am seeing, is that you are passing an object of type `string` to your `convertToUpper()` function that takes a parameter of type `char *`.

Your `convertToUpper()` function should be called like this :

```
convertToUpper(s.c_str());
```

EDIT : In your comment, you have mentioned that you get an error: `cannot call member function const char* TestClass::covertToUpper(char*) without object`

This would mean that your `convertToUpper()` function is in a class called `TestClass`. Since this is a member function, you need to have an instanciated `TestClass` object to use to call your function.

For your purpose, I suggest changing your function declaration to :

```
static const char *convertToUpper(char *str)
```

From there you can call your `convertToUpper()` method this way : `TestClass::convertToUpper(...)`

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I already tried doing that before but I thought I was getting same exception. After adding this again, I am getting a new exception which is `error: cannot call member function const char* TestClass::covertToUpper(char*) without object`

Comment: @david This would mean that your convertToUpper() function is in a class called TestClass. Since this is an instance method, you need to have an instanciated TestClass object to use to call your function. In your case, I suggest adding the keyword "static" in front of "const char *covertToUpper(char *str)" and replacing "convertToUpper(s.c_str())" to "TestClass::convertToUpper(s.c_str())". I'll update my answer.

Comment: If I make that method as static, then it should also work right? And it's ok to make that static as well?

Comment: @david Make your convertToUpper() method static. And call the function using TestClass::convertToUpper(s.c_str())

Comment: Sure. got it now. Now I have another weird error. Sorry for all these silly questions. My background is in Java so taking some time to understand. And now I am getting `error: strdup was not declared in this scope`. I am compiling on my program in Ubuntu 12.04. My gcc version `gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-2ubuntu1~12.04) 4.7.3`

Comment: If this doesn't work, then what is the best way to make a string uppercase?

Comment: @david Make sure you have all the right header files included. strdup is a function inside the "cstring" header file. Make sure you have #include <cstring>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75884/discussion-between-david-and-cubia).

Comment: There are a couple of problems with this. `c_str()` returns a pointer to the first element of an array of constants. conversion from `const char*` to `char*` has been deprecated since C++11. if you modify the contents of the string in `convertToupper` you will invoke UB.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Thanks for mentionning it, feel free to correct my code, I am not as familiar with C++ as I am with C.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious He is making a copy through strdup() though. So he is not modifying the contents of the string directly.

Comment: True...Scratch the UB.